# answer display issue with hitting enter vs clicking "=" (Calculator)

Tags: javascript

All of my code works except for one thing: if I use the buttons on-screen first, THEN use the keyboard, the answer does not display. for example, if I click 5+5 then hit the button "=" I get 10, but if I clear, then type 5+5 and hit enter, the answer does not display.
However, if the page is refreshed I can use the keyboard just fine with no issues, the answer displays.

In my code "enter" is set to do the same thing "=" button is.

I found the source of the problem (I hope) but I'm unsure how to fix it: in my compute function, when I use the keyboard after I used the buttons, my if(isNaN) returns a 1 on the console.log (so I could find where the code was going wrong) I'm not sure why it thinks what's coming in is not a number, because it works fine when the buttons havent been touched.

Here is the code for equals button:

```
equalsButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
    calculator.compute()
    calculator.updateDisplay()
})
```

Here is the code for enter:

```
document.onkeyup = e => {
//code for numbers 1-9 & operations//
else if(e.key === "Enter") {
    calculator.compute()
    calculator.updateDisplay()
    console.log("the answer is " + calculator.compute())
}
```

Here is the compute function code:

```
compute() {
        let computation
        const prev = parseFloat(this.previousOperand)
        const current = parseFloat(this.currentOperand)
        if(isNaN(prev) || isNaN(current)) return 1
        switch(this.operation) {
            case '+':
                computation = prev + current
                break
            case '-':
                computation = prev - current
                break
            case '*':
                computation = prev * current
                break
            case '÷':
                computation = prev / current
                break
            default:
                return
        }
        this.currentOperand = computation
        this.operation = undefined
        this.previousOperand = ''
        console.log(this.currentOperand)
    }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you make this into a code snippet for other visitors? Also, have you tried adding a debug statement inside your `(e.key === "Enter") {}` statement? For example `console.log`?

Comment: does `10+55` not error and produce a `15` result?

Comment: @dandavis 10+55 errors as well

Comment: @LeoDog896 I have actually! i forgot to include it in the code i wrote above, but it turns out that my console.log returns a 1 even when the code does work, so everytime i press enter. Also, how do I make a code snippet? new term for me lol

Comment: to make a snippet, click the page button (has '<>' in it) that appears in the toolbar when you are editing your question. This will allow you to enter separate code snippets for your html, css, and js that should run in the browser so that others can replicate your issue and try to fix it with all the code given

Comment: `compute()` doesn't return anything. What are you expecting `"the answer is " + calculator.compute()` to do?

Comment: ^ as @Barmar mentioned, `compute()` returns nothing, and sets `previousOperand` to a String aka `NaN` which is probably why you keep getting that `1` in your console logs, since it is called twice each time (once in your event handlers, once in your `console.log()` statement

Answer (score 0):

firstly, just as a matter of best practice, you needn't create an object in your click function if you don't need to work with the event--

```js
equalsButton.addEventListener('click',() => {
    calculator.compute()
    calculator.updateDisplay()
})
```

now,

quick fix is to make the keydown event an alias for your click() function =>

```js
else if(e.key === "Enter") {
    equalsButton.click()
//    console.log("the answer is " + calculator.compute())
}
```

i did notice also, you call `calculator.compute()` as the first step of your 'Enter' event handler, and then you call it again in the `console.log()` statement, which clears the previous computation (by setting it to an empty *string* aka `NaN`)

hope all this helps!